# How to pass two connections to mysqli_query for running SELECT INTO query with two different server databases

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

My query is that I need to run a `SELECT INTO` query from One Server Database Table to Another Server Database Table. For that I am having two different `mysqli_connect()` connections so how can I run this query through `mysqli_query` as far as I know we can pass only one connection to it through arguments. Or is there any other way out to perform the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can first create one connection of the first database through `mysqli_query()` and then take that output and store it into temp variable and then create another second server connection and then manipulate your data!

Comment: Hi thanks for the revert but I am not able to understand your point. Are you saying I select the Data from one server DB query and keep it and then again perform the insert query on the second server DB?

Comment: Yes @AayushGupta !